# Open an ASP.Net page containing a Wizard at a different WizardStep to the default starting step?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, aspwizard

I've got an ASP.Net Forms page containing the following (simplified) `<asp:Wizard />` control. I now need to modify this page so that when it is loaded, it loads showing the final step.

Is this possible to do without re-arranging the Wizard steps (Which I'd rather not do)?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updpanHeader" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="false" 
          Style="width: 100%"
          NavigationStyle-CssClass="invisible"
          OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick"
          OnActiveStepChanged="Wizard1_ActiveStepChanged">
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1"
                  StepType="Start">
                    ... wizard form controls for page 1 ...
                </asp:WizardStep>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Step 2"
                  StepType="Step">
                    ... wizard form controls for page 2 ...
                </asp:WizardStep>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep3" runat="server" Title="Step 3"
                  StepType="Step">
                    ... wizard form controls for page 3 ...
                </asp:WizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>
        </asp:Wizard>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've tried swapping the `StepType` of the first and last steps.

I've also tried changing the `ActiveStepIndex` in the `Page_Load` and `Page_LoadComplete` methods, which does work..

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = (Wizard1.WizardSteps.Count - 1);
}
```

..but causes Internet Explorer to show a script warning: "*An error has occurred in the script on this page. Error: Object expected*"

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think you want to activate the index using an OnInit override, otherwise all post-backs are going to trigger the Page_Load.

Also, I believe you want to use the [MoveTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.moveto.aspx) command instead of setting the index. The downfall is you have to use the step's object, but you can get that easily from `Wizard.WizardSteps` I believe.

e.g.

```
private override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
  this.Wizard1.MoveTo(this.WizardStep3);

  base.OnInit(e);
}
```

I may be wrong here though... Please someone correct me if I am.

Comment: Good suggestion Brad, it works but I get the IE script error on page load

Comment: @Andrew: Using the control you posted, but just removing the events bound to `Wizard1` (OnNextButton/OnActiveStep) and using `MoveTo` inside `OnInit` (with something like Demo.aspx?page=2 which I translate to this.WizardStep2) it works fine.

Comment: after I tried your answer, I delved into the error and it's caused by a bit of javascript that runs when the WizardPage is changed - suffice to say it's unrelated!  I'll mark your answer as correct for your suggestion about using OnInit() instead of Page_Load().  Thanks  :o)